# Node.js server app not showing CSS

Tags: html, css, node.js, express

I have the following code on my node.js server (I'm using express):

```
app.get('/appointment/:id',function(req,res){
  res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/html'});
  res.write('<link href="public/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">');
  res.write('<form name="accept" action="http://localhost:8080/appointment/'+ req.params.id+'/1" method="post">');
  res.write('<input id="accept" type="submit" value="Accept">');
  res.write('</form><br>');
  res.write('<form name="decline" action="http://localhost:8080/appointment/'+ req.params.id+'/0" method="post">');
  res.write('<input id="decline" type="submit" value="Decline">');
  res.write('</form><br>');
  res.end();
});
```

In my root folder I have folder appointment/public/css/style.css.
When I open the web page it just displays 2 form buttons but without CSS applied.
The CSS code is:

```
#accept {
  width:50px;
  height:30px;
  background-color:#00FF00;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:120%;
}

#decline {
  width:50px;
  height:30px;
  background-color:#FF0000;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:120%;
}
```

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

**EDIT:** The hierarchy is as follows:
-server_files
--nodeServer.js
--public
---css
----style.css

Comment: Are you able to load the CSS file in another tab?

Comment: As I understood you use express, so you need add this line to you code `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`, and add `/` before `public/css/style.css`

Comment: @RienNeVaPlu͢s no I'm not. When I click on the link it says that it can't execute the GET request. Do I need to add app.get and "serve" the CSS file?

Comment: Yes, you need to serve your static files as Alexander has described. Good luck :)

Comment: @Alexander I already added the `app.use(...)`. Adding `/` before public didn't fix the problem either.

Comment: @remaker If `/public` is your static root directory, then `http://localhost/foo.css`  maps to the file `public/foo.css`. (The name of the static root directory never appears in static HTTP paths; the filesystem's `public` becomes the server's `/` (the root)) You need to use `/css/style.css` in your `<link>`.

Comment: @apsillers Thank you. I didn't understand quite well how all of this is mapped so I didn't know how to deal with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel it's important to share with you the reason of why this problem occurred. Just like other web frameworks, ExpressJs has it's own way of serving static files.

[express.static](http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html) middleware is based on [serve-static](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static?_ga=1.185104169.1059149982.1422847790), and is responsible for serving the static assets of an Express application.

How it works:

- Serve static content for the app from the "public" directory in the application directory

  // GET /style.css etc

  **app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));**
- Mount the middleware at "/static" to serve static content only when their request path is prefixed with "/static"

  // GET /static/style.css etc.

  **app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));**
- Serve static files from multiple directories, but give precedence to "./public" over the others

  **app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));**

  **app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/files'));**

  **app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/uploads'));**

*I checked your folder structure, i suggest you to keep your **public directory in the same level as server_files directory** and also **nodeServer.js file outside of your server_files** because it's the main file using which you are using to start your application.*

Then in your **nodeServer.js** you can do this:

```
app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

After doing this, all your static assets in public directory can be accessed in html templates or any other templating engine that you might be using. For example :

```
<link href="public/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Please note the order of your middle wares in **nodeServer.js**. I hope this helps.